# OpenStreetMap POIs with Nominatim - error

Tags: osmdroid

I'm using this tutorial: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_2

I set this Code in my Project:

```
NominatimPOIProvider poiProvider = new NominatimPOIProvider();
ArrayList<POI> pois = poiProvider.getPOICloseTo(startPoint, "cinema", 50, 0.1);
```

But I get some Errors:
NominatimPOIProvider (String) in NominatimPOIProvider cannot be applied  to ()

and

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/Request$Builder;
>                         at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.utils.HttpConnection.doGet(HttpConnection.java:65)
>                         at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.utils.BonusPackHelper.requestStringFromUrl(BonusPackHelper.java:70)
>                         at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.location.NominatimPOIProvider.getThem(NominatimPOIProvider.java:83)
>                         at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.location.NominatimPOIProvider.getPOICloseTo(NominatimPOIProvider.java:133)
>                         at x.x.UserArea.onCreate(UserArea.java:152)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.Request$Builder"

Answer (score 1):

Error:

> NominatimPOIProvider (String) in NominatimPOIProvider cannot be
>   applied to ()

is caused by an absence of nonparametric constructor for NominatimPOIProvider. You are required to specify user agent which will be used in headers sent to a Nominatim service provider. More details can be found in [this issue](https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/issues/284) and in [usage policy of openstreetmap](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/).

Use something like:

```
NominatimPOIProvider poiProvider = new NominatimPOIProvider("YourUserAgentSpecificForYourApplicationOrWhatever");
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved with:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
```